# Flexbox columns with video object-fit: cover

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to all kinds of coding and I know what I've written here below is a morass.
So what I'm trying to achieve is some text with a header taking up about 60% of the width while a video autoplays on the remaining 40%. I wanted the text to define the height of the video container with the video just filling it out - I tried with *object-fit: cover;* but without luck. On top of that I also want to put and svg on top of the right edge of the video to create a wave edge as you can probably see in my current progress. Right now I've set both the svg and the video to *height: 500px* but actually I just want the video to fill the container as described earlier and the svg to have a 100% height of the container.

Hope this makes sense, and once again I'm sorry for my limited knowledge, but would really appreciate if some of you could help me out ✨

Thanks a lot in advance

```css
.simplewrap {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: -6rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-item1 {
  width: 55%;
  height:100%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.flex-item2 {
  width: 40%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover; 
}

.imgbannercollec {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="simplewrap">
<li class="flex-item1">
      <h1 style="font-size: 30px;">
        Heading
      </h1>
<p>Det er meget almindeligt at opleve problemer med at få orgasme. En rutine med en god bækkenbundstræner kan hjælpe dig med få bedre muskulatur, forbedre blærekontrol og give dig stærkere orgasmer. Vi kan alle sammen have gavn af at træne vores bækkenbund. Sundhed er en af pillerne i et lykkeligt liv, og intim sundhed bør bestemt ikke undervurderes.
</p>
</li>
<li class="flex-item2">
<img class="imgbannercollec" height="500px" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/2852/9698/files/Artboard_1slange.png?v=1642692447">
<video id="loop_me" autoplay loop muted height="500px">
  <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/2852/9698/files/peesc.mp4?v=1643192535" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the construction of your elements is badly designed to do what you want, as you put flex-direction in row, all your two blocks are on top of each other, so I suggest you go through the positioning you put a position: relative; has your .simplewrap then position: absolute; in your .flex-item2 also add the lower z-index and move it from right to left and up

Comment: Thanks a lot - will do so :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the margin-top: -6rem; from